Разноцветный календарь на wpf
На winforms сделал свой контрол и реализовал разукрашивание дней в зависимости от категории к которой принадлежит день. У любого дня можно сменить категорию, в календаре отображается актуальный дате цвет.

Начал реализовывать аналогичный функционал на ПО, написанное на WPF. Как проще/удобнее реализовать окрашивание дней в календаре?(используются контролы telerik - RadCalendar).

Привязать листбокс к коллекции объектов с названием строки и цветом. С календарём может не получиться, зависит от возможностей используемого контрола. Но WPF тем и хорош, что шаблоны и стили можно переопределять полностью для любого контрола. Правой кнопкой по контролу в дизайнере и выбрать редактирование копии шаблона, и он добавится в XAML, а там творите с ним что хотите.

Примерно понятно в каком направлении нужно двигаться. Нужно будет изучить материал и попрактиковаться...как будет результат выложу сюда.
